# xpath запрос к html выдает "кракозябры"

Tags: php, xpath

Я хочу получить дату создания объявления в авито. Должно выглядеть так: "сегодня в 9:30", а выходит Â· ÑÐµÐ³Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ñ Ð² 09:23. Помогите пожалуйста

```
<?php 
        $url="https://www.avito.ru/cheboksary/avtomobili/audi_a5_2014_2522896601";
        $dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $htm=getPageByUrl($url);
        $dom->loadHTML( $htm);
        libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
        $xpath = new DomXPath( $dom );
        $res=$xpath->query('//span[@class="text-text-1PdBw text-size-s-1PUdo" and @data-marker="item-view/item-date"]'); 
        
        foreach($res as $node){
            echo $node->nodeValue;
            
        }
        function getPageByUrl($url)
            {
                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                
                $result = curl_exec($curl);
        
                if ($result === false) {            
                    echo "Ошибка CURL: " . curl_error($curl);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return $result;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Видно, что проблема в плохой погоде, не в кодировке же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас разная кодировка, установите заголовок.
в формате хтмл

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

или пхп

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Или в настройках сервера апач в httpd.conf

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```